# awk function to filter each column of a file in a loop based on value obtained from a second file

Tags: arrays, awk

I am looking for an awk solution that enable to filter file2.txt for two conditions.

I have two files:
**file1.txt**

```
t1 9
t2 8
t3 5
```

**file2.txt**

```
t1 t2 t3
A/A:10,0:10 B/B:0,2:2 n/n
A/B:10,8:18 A/B:2,8:10 n/n
A/B:0,2:2 n/n B/B:0,1:1
```

| t1 | t2 | t3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A/A:10,0:10 | B/B:0,2:2 | n/n |
| A/B:10,8:18 | A/B:2,8:10 | n/n |
| A/B:0,2:2 | n/n | B/B:0,1:1 |

**desired output:**

```
t1 t2 t3
A/A:10,0:10 n/n n/n
A/B:10,8:18 n/n n/n
n/n n/n n/n
```

| t1 | t2 | t3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A/A:10,0:10 | n/n | n/n |
| A/B:10,8:18 | n/n | n/n |
| n/n | n/n | n/n |

Based on the values of **file1.txt** , for which I was able to create an array which store the value in B column

`awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t"}  FILENAME=="file1.txt" { descr[$1]=$2 ; next }`

I would like to filter the **file2.txt**, by iterating through the columns for the following conditions, in order to obtained what reported in the desired output. All samples in the header of **file2.txt** are included in **file1.txt** and the order is the same.

1. the third value (split by *:*) should be within a specific interval based on corresponding value from **file1.txt**
   For example the first value of sample *t1* [10]:
   10>=(9/2) && 10<=(9*2) - is within the interval and thus keep the string as it is. The number 2 used in the division and multiplication is hard-coded and the number 9 is obtained from **file1.txt**. If not within the interval, then write n/n (for example first value for sample *t2*).
2. if the ratio of the first value/(sum of values in the second field) is included within an interval 0.1-0.25 or 0.75-0.9, then write n/n (split by *,* in this case).

For example second value of sample *t2* [2,8] has a ratio 2/10=0.2, which is included in the interval, and thus need to set to n/n the field. The number 10 is derived from the sum of the two values in the field, separated by comma.

I tried a combination of for loop and if / split conditions, but I have some issues in order to iterate through the columns using the array, combined with the conditions.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Thanks to took the time to nicely format your input, but I'm sorry to tell you that raw text would be better here as sample inputs than markdown tables.   
Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 2nd `t2` value of `2,8` is processed as `2/8` (?) which is `0.25` (not `0.2` as in the description); 1st `t1` value of `10,0` is processed as `10/0` (?) which is a 'divide by zero' error so what's the rule for an error like this?

Comment: Thank you @GillesQuénot for pointing this out.  I totally agree with you and edited the question hopefully in the corrected way.

Comment: @markp-fuso sorry for the mistake, I have edited the question now with the correct values of the ratio (2/10).  As you correctly pointed out, in case of division by zero, if the first condition is still true, the string should be kept has is, if this is feasible somehow.

Comment: I don't understand how you go from `2,8` to `2/10`? ignore the `,8`? where does the `10` come from?

Comment: will all column headers from `file2.txt` have a matching row in `file1.txt`?  will the rows from `file1.txt` and the column headers from `file2.txt` be in the same order (eg, `t1` is first in both files, `t2` is second in both files)?

Comment: @markp-fuso sorry for the lack of clarity. 10 is the sum obtained from 2 and 8, from second field [2,8]. And regarding the other question, yes, all column headers in file2.txt have a match in file1.txt. Concerning the order, they are in the same order. I was trying with the array to be fully sure of having the correspondence between the two files.

Comment: these additional details you've provided need to be added to the question; not everyone is going to read through the comments trying to piece together the whole/bigger picture

Comment: where does the `2` (`9/2`, `9*2`) come from? is that hardcoded or derived from the input data?

Comment: for `(file2.txt) t1 == A/B:10,8:18` ... `18 > (9/2)` is true but `18 < (9*2)` if false, so why isn't this entry replaced with `n/n` in the desired output?

Comment: you've stated you tried *`for loop and if / split conditions`* ... please update the question with this coding attempt; hopefully some of your coding logic (especially related to the various calculations) will help clarify some of the confusion

Comment: @markp-fuso Thank you for pointing out additional mistakes. The intervals are closed (>= and <=), and I have edited the question properly. Hopefully now it is more clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- the values: 2, 0.1, 0.25, 0.75 and 0.9 are hard-coded.
- the intervals are `closed`, meaning the endpoints are included
  (if not, drop the `=` signs next to `<` and `>`).
- the column names in file1.txt may or may not be in the same order
  as the heder in file2.txt.

then would you please try the following:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" -v nn="n/n" '
    NR==FNR {a[$1] = $2; next}                                  # read file1.txt to associate the numerator value with the column name
    FNR==1 {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) b[i] = a[$i]                  # read the header line in file2.txt to associate the numerator value with the field number
        print                                                   # print the header line
        next
    }
    {                                                           # process bodies in file2.txt
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {                             # loop over the fields
            if ($i != nn) {
                split($i, c, /:/)
                split(c[2], d, /,/)
                if (! (c[3] >= b[i] / 2 && c[3] <= b[i] * 2))   # test the condition 1
                    $i = nn
                if (d[1] + d[2] > 0) {                          # avoid division-by-zero
                    ratio = d[1] / (d[1] + d[2])
                    if (ratio >= 0.1 && ratio <= 0.25 || ratio >= 0.75 && ratio <= 0.9)
                                                                # test the condition 2
                        $i = nn
                }
            }
        }
        print                                                   # print the line
    }
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Output:

```
t1      t2      t3
A/A:10,0:10     n/n     n/n
A/B:10,8:18     n/n     n/n
n/n     n/n     n/n
```

BTW the 2nd column of the 2nd line `B/B:0,10:10` in the desired output
should be a typo for `n/n`.

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanation. As you correctly pointed out, the 2nd column of the 2nd line was a typo. I updated accordingly.